# How to get Node to trust root certs in my Windows OS certificate store?

Tags: node.js, windows, security, certificate-store

My organization has pre-installed its own root certificates in our machines to enable it to inspect HTTPS traffic.  The browsers don't complain since they trust the OS certificates by default.  This causes me all sorts of problem using NodeJS though, which does NOT trust those certificates.

Node has the option to extend the certs it will trust by setting the [`NODE_EXTRA_CA_CERTS` option](https://nodejs.org/api/cli.html#cli_node_extra_ca_certs_file) and I'm trying to to employ this.  Problem is: this option takes a file:

> NODE_EXTRA_CA_CERTS=file
>
> When set, the well known "root" CAs (like VeriSign) will be extended with the extra certificates in file. The file should consist of one or more trusted certificates in PEM format.

Where do I get this file on Windows?

Answer (score 0):

You need to get the root certificates from your organization. Note that `NODE_EXTRA_CA_CERTS` only accept `.pem` file. If it is a `.cer` file, use `openssl x509 -inform der` command to convert the file to pem format.